# Liquibase does not add interval to current_timestamp

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I use postgres DB, I faced an issue with liquibase adding interval to the current time as default value:

```
<property name="expired" value="current_timestamp + interval '60 days'" 
dbms="postgresql"/>

<addColumn tableName="user">
        <column name="expired" type="timestamp" 
                               defaultValueDate="${expired}">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
```

Expired property always returns current date without adding 60 days.
Is it possible? Or is there some mistakes in value field?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `defaultValueComputed` for an expression.

But apparently there is a bug in Liquibase that prevents it from parsing an expression with `current_timestamp` correctly. But using `now()` seems to work:

```
<property name="expired" value="now() + interval '60 days'" dbms="postgresql"/>  

<addColumn tableName="user">
  <column name="expired" type="timestamp" defaultValueComputed="${expired}">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
</addColumn>
```

---

Unrelated, but: `user` is a reserved keyword. It is a very bad idea to create a table with that name.