# How to add a datetime column with a default value of three months from today's date in Liquibase?

Tags: sql, database, liquibase

I have a column like so:

```
<changeSet id="myId" author="me">
<comment>Add new default value for DATE column</comment>
<addDefaultValue tableName="Foo"
                 columnName="DATE"
                 defaultValueComputed="${sysdate}"/>
</changeSet>
```

And this adds a default value of today's date and time.

I want to add another column that is today's date/time + 3 months. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: And what is the underlying DBMS?

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server

Comment: Oh, and `sysdate` works?

Comment: Oh sorry. I also have this property added `<property name="sysdate" value="GETDATE()" dbms="mssql"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I've used `NOW() + interval '1.5 days'` to set a column to 1.5 days in the future.

Try `NOW() + interval '3 months'` for 3 months in the future.

I know this works for yaml, but I haven't tested it for xml.

Also, see here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52513364/1250830